# how to remove the flicker and shadows of an scnnode in swift

Tags: swift4, xcode9, arkit

I am using a directional SCNLight attached above the chair. The shadow around the legs of the chair are flickering and there is unwanted shadows on the seat of the chair.

[image: .]

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm tweaking the light shadowSampleCount property but it affects performance and mitigates the problem without solving it